# The product $X=\prod_{s\in S}X_s$ is a $k$-space, then $X_s$ is a $k$-space for each $s\in S$.

Tags: general-topology

**Definition:** Let $X$ be a topological space and $A\subset X$. We say that $A$ is a $\textbf{$k$-closed}$ in $X$ if for all compact $K\subset X$ it happens that $A\cap K$ is closed at $K$. So we have that $X$ is a $\textbf{$k$-space}$ if all $k$-closed from $X$ is closed at $X$.

I want to prove the following statement.

**Theorem:** Let $\{ (X_s, \tau_s) \colon s\in S \}$ be a non-empty family of non-empty topological spaces and $X=\prod_{s\in S}X_s$ with the product topology. If $X$ is a $k$-space, then $X_s$ is a $k$-space for each $s\in S$.

This is my attempt (I have some incomplete details that I still don't know how to fill out)

**Proof:** Let $s_0\in S$ and $A\subset X_{s_0}$ be a $k$-closed set. Consider $B=A\times \prod_{s\neq s_0}X_s$. I want to prove that $B$ is a $k$-closed in $X$.

Let $K$ be a compact subset of $X$. Clearly $\rho_s(K)=K_s$ is a compact subset of $X_s$ for each $s\in S$, where $\rho_s \colon X \rightarrow X_s$ is the projection function and $K\subset \prod_{s\in S}K_s$. Then to show $B\cap K$ is closed in $K$ it´s is sufficient to show that $B\cap \prod_{s\in S}K_s$ is closed in $\prod_{s\in S}K_s$ **(I don´t know why it is sufficient prove $B\cap \prod_{s\in S}K_s$ is closed in $\prod_{s\in S}K_s$)**. Note that:

$$
B\cap \prod_{s\in S}K_s=(A\times \prod_{s\neq s_0}X_s)\cap \prod_{s\in S}K_s=(A\times \prod_{s\neq s_0}X_s)\cap (K_{s_0}\times \prod_{s\neq s_0}K_s)=(A\cap K_{s_0}) \times (\prod_{s\neq s_0}X_s \cap \prod_{s\neq s_0}K_s)=(A\cap K_{s_0})\times \prod_{s\neq s_0}K_s.
$$

Since $A$ is $k$-closed in $X_{s_0}$ we conclude that $B\cap \prod_{s\in S}K_s$ is closed in $\prod_{s\in S}K_s$ **(why $B\cap \prod_{s\in S}K_s$ is closed in $\prod_{s\in S}K_s$?)**. Then $B$ is a $k$-closed in $X$, and since $X$ is a $k$-space, we have $B$ is closed in $X$.

We know that the projection function $\rho_{s_0} \colon X \rightarrow X_{s_0}$ is is continuous, suprajective, and open. Then
$$
\rho_{s_0}(X-B)=\rho_{s_0}(\rho_{s_0}^{-1}(X_{s_0})-B)=X_{s_0}-\rho_{s_0}(B)=X_{s_0}-A,
$$
is open in $X_{s_0}$ and therefore $A$ is closed in $X_{s_0}$. Finally $X_s$ is a $k$-space for each $s\in S$.

Do you have any suggestions for the details that I need to prove? Assuming these details are already proven, is my proof correct?